# Trying to make an array of latitudes and longitudes based on cities in a mySQL database using Google Maps API

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to make an array of latitudes and longitudes of the cities I have stored in a mySQL database using Google Maps API.

The array should look like this:

```
var markers = [
    { lat: 45.5235, lng: -122.6762, name: "Portland" },
    { lat: 47.6062, lng: -122.3321, name: "Seattle" },
    { lat: 34.0522, lng: -118.2437, name: "Los Angeles" },
    { lat: 32.7153, lng: -117.1573, name: "San Diego" }
];
```

Here is the code I am using to try to achieve this:

```
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

    var markers = [

    <?php

    //orgnize fans by city
    $query = "SELECT city, state, COUNT(*) fans FROM users GROUP BY city ORDER BY fans DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        var address = echo '"'$row['city'].", ".$row['state']'"';

        geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
                           var latitude = point.y;
                           var longitude = point.x;
        });
        echo "{ lat: \"".latitude.", lng: ".longitude.", name: "'"'.$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].'"'"},\n ";
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    ?>

    ];
```

I am receiving the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR

Comment: Please clarify if you would like the array to be in PHP or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
                           var latitude = point.y;
                           var longitude = point.x;
        });
```

This code is not PHP. Few echos are missing. And line above that is also wierd.